# Is there a way to prevent Windows 10 & Software Installs to split installation data into Program FIles/ProgramData/AppData/Documents etc

Tags: windows, installation, file-location

I am wondering if there is a way to prevent what I mentioned in the title.
I'd like to have 1 Folder for each installed software. I wouldn't mind having sub directories inside for AppData/Documents etc..

I know there are reasons why Windows has these locations, but it makes things really annoying to locate. Just one of a 1000 examples: I am running a server for a game I am playing. Some of the files are in User/Documents, some are inside %AppData%, and some are in Program Files. To configure the server I have to navigate to all of those different locations. Yes, I could make shortcuts, set favorites in the explorer.

But wouldnt it just be way more comfortable to have 1 location per software?

Its just something thats getting on my nerves, tbh, and I know its the same way on Mac os with 2 different hidden Library folders etc.

If I install something on my OS, I would like to be in control where data is being installed and that its not spread around on my system.

Comment: One word - NO .

Comment: The only manual change is the install directory if the installer offers it via the GUI or if the installer supports installing via `msiexec` _(some do, many don't)_; if the latter, public properties [`PROPERTY=PropertyValue`] for locations could be set if supported _(most don't)_. Install/data directories are configured in a sane manner, as software will only install to `%ProgramFiles%`, `%ProgramFiles(x86)%`, `%ProgramData%`, `%AppData%`, or `%LocalAppData%`, whereas program settings files are stored within: `%ProgramData%`, `%AppData%`, `%LocalAppData%`, or directories within `%UserProfile%`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to prevent Windows 10 & Software Installs to split
> installation data into Program FIles/ProgramData/AppData/Documents etc

No.

The two areas are for different purposes:

Program Files for general installation for all users of the computer.

AppData for User data.

There are other variables for user data (this user, all users, and so on).

But the two folders do not go into one single folder.

That is a Windows design.

Comment: It’s not possible due to the fact, the application could ignore any efforts, to change this behavior.  As a programmer I can specify where I want to write data to, Microsoft makes it clear, where certain types of data should exist in. In fact going against that logic is extremely difficult, almost to the point, it’s nearly impossible to do so even as a programmer

Answer (score 1):

This is generally not possible, no. Because you cannot (easily) change a program’s logic.

The paths are most likely hard-coded in the software itself. It is programmed to put stuff that is shared between users in a subfolder of the *Common Application Data* location. It is programmed to put stuff that is not shared between users in a subfolder of the *Application Data* folder. It is programmed to put non-syncable private data in a subfolder of the *Local Application Data* folder.

The example you gave is also just a result of bad decisions made by the developer. It’s not really about some Microsoft guidelines or whatever.

Some software offers a portable mode. Maybe check out [PortableApps.com](https://portableapps.com/).

If you otherwise want to be in control, use free and open source software and change the paths as desired.